# Laravel 5.1 Snappy PDF overwrite

Tags: php, pdf, laravel-5.1

Is there an option to overwrite the existing PDF file?

I have this function:

```
public function quote($id){

    $quote          = Quotes::find($id);
    $last_quote     = sprintf("%'.04d\n", $quote->quote_number);
    $customer       = Customer::find($quote->customer_id);
    $items          = $quote->Items()->get();
    $fullinfo       = json_decode($quote->fullinfo);
    $token          = $quote->Tokens()->first();

    $data = [
        'quote'         => $quote,
        'last_quote'    => $last_quote,
        'customer'      => $customer,
        'items'         => $items,
        'fullinfo'      => $fullinfo,
        'token'         => $token,
    ];

    $pdf = App::make('snappy.pdf.wrapper');

    $pdf->LoadView('quotes.quote_print', $data)
        ->setOption('page-size', 'A4');
    $path = storage_path() . "/quotes/{$customer->name}/cotizacion.pdf";
    $pdf->save($path);
    return $pdf->stream();


}
```

The problem is that when i run that function for the second time i get a file already exist error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What i did was to add the overwrite function to save(), like this:

```
public function save($filename, $overwrite = true)
{

    if ($this->html)
    {
        $this->snappy->generateFromHtml($this->html, $filename, $this->options, $overwrite);
    }
    elseif ($this->file)
    {
        $this->snappy->generate($this->file, $filename, $this->options, $overwrite);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

I have made a pull request for this: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy/pull/76 ,  but this uses $overwrite = false as default

Answer (score 0):

If assume you are using **barryvdh/laravel-snappy** with **laravel 5.1**

The function `save()` you are using to save doesn't support overwrite flag, it internally calls `generateFromHtml` that does support overwrite flag, the fourth argument.

see the *save* method in `\vendor\barryvdh\laravel-snappy\src\PdfWrapper.php`

```
public function save($filename)
{

    if ($this->html)
    {
        $this->snappy->generateFromHtml($this->html, $filename, $this->options);
    }
    elseif ($this->file)
    {
        $this->snappy->generate($this->file, $filename, $this->options);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

I would recommend you to use the following method of saving the view to pdf

```
public function quote($id){

    $quote          = Quotes::find($id);
    $last_quote     = sprintf("%'.04d\n", $quote->quote_number);
    $customer       = Customer::find($quote->customer_id);
    $items          = $quote->Items()->get();
    $fullinfo       = json_decode($quote->fullinfo);
    $token          = $quote->Tokens()->first();

    $data = [
        'quote'         => $quote,
        'last_quote'    => $last_quote,
        'customer'      => $customer,
        'items'         => $items,
        'fullinfo'      => $fullinfo,
        'token'         => $token,
    ];

    $pdf = App::make('snappy.pdf.wrapper');

    $html = view('quotes.quote_print', $data))->render();
    $path = storage_path() . "/quotes/{$customer->name}/cotizacion.pdf";

    //public function generateFromHtml($html, $output, array $options = array(), $overwrite = false)
    $pdf->generateFromHtml($html, $path,[],$overwrite = true);
    return $pdf->stream();


}
```

Hope this helps,

K

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue today in laravel.

*Exit with code 1 due to network error: ContentNotFoundError*

**I tried to wrap my all css and script link with url() function.**

```
Example:
Replace
        <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
to         
    <link href="{{url('/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
And Replace
    <script src="{{url('/js/jquery-2.1.1.js')}}"></script>
To
    <script src="{{url('/js/jquery-2.1.1.js')}}"></script>
```

and my code working. Now every thing is fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to delete the file to be overwritten.

**Versions**

> knplabs/knp-snappy        v1.3.1
> knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle v1.8.0

PDF creation logic (running under Ibexa community edition/Symfony)

```
private function _makePdf(ContentView $view) {
        $pdfFilename = $this->baseDir . $this->pdfUrl . '.pdf';
        unlink($pdfFilename);
        $html = $this->render($view->getTemplateIdentifier(), $view->getParameters());
        $this->knpSnappyPdf->generateFromHtml(
                $html->getContent(),
                $pdfFilename
        );
    }
```